# Is it OK to put a sleeping MacBook pro (Mid 2015) in your backpack and carry around?

Tags: macbook-pro, sleep-wake

Is it OK to put this MacBook Pro in my backpack to carry around?
[image]

Appreciate hardware analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mid-2015 model is only available with SSD. I.e. you do do not have a hard drive with moving parts to worry about.

It is therefore safe to carry the MacBook Pro in your backpack and carry it around.

Just be sensible: don't drop the backpack, don't sit on it, etc.

Comment: So I guess the key is only the moving parts? What about the heat? Does mackbook accumulate too much heat while sleeping and in the bag?

Comment: If you're worried about the MBP running (and generating heat) while in the bag, disable the [PowerNap](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204032) feature.

Comment: @zlin No, it does not accumulate too much heat. Even if the software was defective and it did accumulate heat, the hardware has built-in protection that disables the software before it becomes a real problem.